# How do I send a command after I clicked a button on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my code:

```
    up.setOnClickListener{GlobalScope.launch{cor.TCP(toWrite="Up")}}
    down.setOnClickListener{GlobalScope.launch{cor.TCP(toWrite="Down")}}
    left.setOnClickListener{GlobalScope.launch{cor.TCP(toWrite="Left")}}
    right.setOnClickListener{GlobalScope.launch{cor.TCP(toWrite="Right")}}
```

It sends a TCP request to the pre-defined socket and port. There are 4 buttons: up, down, left and right. I want to send a command after the button is pressed, because I am controlling a robot using this, so when I send "Up", it is moving upwards indefinitely, and when I stop pressing the button, I want to send a stop command. So, how do I send a command after I click a button? Thank you very much!

Comment: No. I already know how to send a TCP request, in fact, it is mentioned in my code. I am asking how to execute an operation after I pressed/clicked a button on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the kotlin version of @cesarmarch's answer to be more descriptive in your usecase

**Firstly**

Your class needs to implement `View.OnTouchListener`

**Secondly**

You need to override the onTouch method

```
override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (view) {
       up -> {
        when (motionEvent.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
              GlobalScope.launch{cor.TCP(toWrite="Up")}
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                //... Stop the robot here
            }
        }
    }
    down -> {
        when (motionEvent.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
              GlobalScope.launch{cor.TCP(toWrite="Down")}
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                //... Stop the robot here
            }
        }
    }
    left -> {
        //... Do similar motion check as above
    }
    right -> {
        //... Do similar motion check as above
    }
  }
   return true
}
```

**Finally**

Set the listener on the buttons

```
 ...
 up.setOnTouchListener(this)
 down.setOnTouchListener(this)
 left.setOnTouchListener(this)
 right.setOnTouchListener(this)
 ...
```

Comment: Could you explain why to use this instead of up.useOnClickListener alone?

Comment: I sucessfully used the code. Don't know if it will work, but it's still good to learn something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you should use a `OnTouchListener` instead.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // Button pressed - send whatever move command
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        // Button unpressed - send STOP command
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use the `View` to detect which button has been touched

Comment: How can I use View to get the touched button?

Comment: Use the view id to get the touched button. Something like `switch v.id { case R.id.up: // This is the up button }`. The id is defined either on your layout file or when you create the view in code.

Comment: I did it in Kotlin via `up.setOnTouchListener`, but the View parameter is unused, am I supposed to use it to get the button? Because I did it via the aforementioned function, which is only binding to the up button.

Comment: If you directly set the `OnTouchListener` to each button, you don't have to use the View parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using *View.onTouchListener* instead of onClickListener. OnTouchListener gives you access to the MotionEvent of the view, in your case, you'll probably need MotionEvent.ACTION_UP and MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, use that to filter what action should be triggered.

You can always refer to the docs:

[View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener)

[MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Comment: I tried using up.onTouchListener() which also gives me access to the MotionEvent. Is there any difference or?

Comment: Buttons extends TextView, so it also have access to the View class properties, so your button "up" is already a View, setting up "up.onTouchListener()" is exactly the solution I was thinking about. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

You cannot stop coroutine in [GlobalScope](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc). Define [custom scope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html) in your class

Comment: This is not an answer, I will fix this next time.

Comment: This is an interesting link (for someone trying to switch over to Kotlin from Java) and I would not be surprised if it's part of the solution. But it's almost a link-only answer, and I've seen recently that posts can be removed from sites like Medium. So could you add a little more information here why one should avoid using GlobalScope?

Comment: I've also read both those articles, but I'd also like an overview answer, as to why I should avoid GlobalScope.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question neither.